# JPA EntityManager not being injected in Java EE app

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I am receiving a `NullPointerException` with the following code and configuration, and I am not sure why. I would appreciate some help in debugging this issue.

File *persistence.xml*:

```
<persistence-unit name="adismPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.adism.domain.Ad</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adism" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "ads") public class Ad {
    private Integer adId;
    private String adTitle;

    public Ad(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name="adid")
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getAdId(){
        return adId;
    }


    public void setAdId(Integer adId){
        this.adId = adId;
    }

    @Column(name="adtitle")
    public String getAdTitle(){
        return this.adTitle;
    }

     public void setAdTitle(String title){
        this.adTitle = title;
    }

}
```

DAO Implementation:

```
public class AdDaoImpl implements AdDao{

  @PersistenceContext   
  public EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override   
  public void save(Ad ad){
     entityManager.persist(ad);   
   }
```

}

When I run following code in JSP, I get *NullPointerException*

```
Ad ad = new Ad();
ad.setAdId(1000);
ad.setAdTitle("JPA pure");
AdDao newDao = new AdDaoImpl();
newDao.save(ad);
```

Comment: where are you injecting it?

Comment: just edited the question, I am injecting it like @PersistenceContext public EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: no idea :S doing it for first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do `AdDao newDao = new AdDaoImpl();` your container will not known where to inject the EntityManager.

If you are using JBoss or Glassfish (or someother kind of EJB Containner) you need to declare AdDao as EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class AdDao () {}
```

And you will use it in your servlet like:

```
@EJB
public AdDao ejb;
```

PS.: I would not inject a DAO in a controller. The best is to use other classes between both, but if you are new to this kind of technology start with it.

---

If you are using a solution without JPA you can do something like:
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("YOUR_PERSISTENCE_UNIT"); // store it in your class

```
public void yourMethod(){
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    // do your stuff here
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: ah, I might be doing something completely stupid, I am running this app in idea and have configured tomcat with it, is that right combination for it?

Comment: just found that tomcat by default cant host EJBs and it just implements Servlet specification.

Comment: is there any other way to use JPA?

Comment: I just edited my answer. I believe that you should start studying the basics of JPA. Here you can find a material: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-book-first-steps-and-detailed-concepts/

Comment: If you are not using an EJB container then Spring would be the most commonly used alternative. See, for example: http://www.alexecollins.com/content/tutorial-hibernate-jpa-spring-mvc-part-2/

Comment: I know I can use JPA + Spring + Tocmat , what I was trying to learn is to write a JPA simple app without Spring which I guess is not possible if I want to use Tomcat because its not an EJB container?

Comment: You could use TomEE that is a Tomcat version with EJB. [=